# From the success: function(object) { console.log(object) }, i am getting the responce object, But not able to fetch the particular object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am getting the response object as :

```
{"emailID":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Employees","objectId":"Ap8MmrvYUl"},"slotNo":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"ParkingSlots","objectId":"ASyr5tgBtl"},"vehicleType":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"TypeOfVehicle","objectId":"F5R4VRExA6"},"isDeallocated":false,"isReserved":false,"allocatedDate":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-02-11T09:50:00.000Z"},"objectId":"earFXqNB65","createdAt":"2014-02-11T09:50:38.169Z","updatedAt":"2014-02-11T09:53:05.794Z","__type":"Object","className":"ParkingAllocationStatus"}
```

Needed:

I want to get the **iso** value of **allocatedDate**, 
tried using the

```
var obj = object.get("allocatedDate");
console.log(obj.iso);
```

But resulted in error like : get is not a function or undefined.

Comment: What's `.get()` supposed to be?  If that's a JavaScript object all you need is `object.allocatedDate.iso`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @FelixKling, dear friend, i tried this way, but it is not allowing, says "iso" is undefined. Note: i am using parse.com/docs SDK, not normal javascript

Comment: Maybe you should provide some more context and post more of your code. I find the documentation pretty self explanatory actually: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects.